# Increase In memory size of image from RGB to Gray ,OpenCV

Tags: python, memory-management, opencv, image-conversion

I have started to explore deep into image Processing. Curious to know the answer of a simple question(which I tried googling but I guess I could not find a satisfactory answer):
I have an RGB image:

[image]

then I applied simple OpenCV command:
img=cv2.imread(r'E:\opencv\elephant.jpg',0)

cv2.imwrite('updated_elephant.jpg',img)

and finally got the output image:

[image: see the memory used which is more than RGB image]

Coming back to the question, why is there an increase in the size of the output image?(same thing happens with cv2.cvtColor() function.)Any insight or example relating to this would be appreciated.

Thank You for Your Sincere attention.

Comment: When you cv2.imread the image is decompressed. When recompressing, the compression quality, method etc can be very different from original, therefore you cannot expect a similar size.

Answer (score 3):

JPEG is a lossy format, well described on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). Have a read.

Encoders are allowed to make decisions about how they encode the data. Some will down-sample the colour one way, some another way and yet others will not do chroma-subsampling at all.

Some encoders will use integers for quantisation because it is faster on some processors, others may use floating point because they value accuracy more.

Some coders use the JPEG suggested tables of coefficients for discarding high frequencies, some use their own tables - this is the `quality` setting.

Therefore you will potentially get different filesizes and renditions on different platforms, or on the same platform with a different encoder, or on the same platform with the same encoder but a different software version.

---

If you want to look at chroma sub-sampling and quality settings in more detail, use **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
magick identify -verbose YOURIMAGE.JPG info:
```

---

If you want to spend several hours studying JPEG in minute detail, I commend this series of videos to you - [link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLpsTn9TA_Q8VMDyOPrDKmSJYt1DLgDZU4&v=CPT4FSkFUgs).

Comment: Thankyou for the response.I have understood and got the idea in a vague sense.I do know working of JPEG a bit but there's one more question?why there is a memory difference when i use "cv2.imread fn with 0 parameter "and "cv2.imread normally with default 1 parameter ,converting it to gray using cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)".(Basically looking for some insight into these function working).

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by *"memory difference"*. Memory=RAM, in my book. JPEG's are generally held fully decompressed in RAM. That means a 1920x1080 8-bit greyscale image will take the same amount of RAM whether it started life as a 253,000 byte JPEG, a 32,000 byte PNG or a 23,578 byte GIF or a 2MB TIFF.